# Threads VS Processes (C)

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, time, process

I made 3 different versions of a program. This program multiplies matrixes.

1. The first version does it sequentially.
2. The second divides the first matrix in 2, and creates 2 processes to multiply each of them.
3. The third version does the same as (2) but using threads.

I'm using very large matrixes to test this, and I have 2 CPU.

I used 'time' to test times:

```
1. real: 5.6s / user: 5.2s / sys: 0.4s

2. real: 2.9s / user: 2.5s / sys: 0.4s

3. real: 2.7s / user: 4.2s / sys: 1.0s
```

'real time' went about what I was expecting. However, I've got 2 questions:

1. What is happening in (3)? Why is 'user time' larger than 'real time'?
2. Shouldn't 'sys time' be less using threads? Knowing that process creation takes longer than thread creation...

Comment: Apparently, your version of the `time` command understands threading on multi-core processors. Each thread (running on its own core) takes 2.1 user seconds and 0.5 sys seconds, which would give you 2.6 real seconds. The same thing doesn't happen in the second version because `time` doesn't take the second process into account.

Comment: *"Knowing that process creation takes longer than thread creation..."* - The creation takes very short time. It's not a factor here.

Comment: How do you recombine the results of the separate multiplications in (2) and (3)?  Are you just measuring the I/O time of printing the result appropriately?

Comment: I use pipe() in (2) and a global array of matrixes in (3) (that is global to both threads). Also, there is no I/O. I have a function that randomizes the matrixes. I just set the number of rows and lines of each matrix, and the program generates them. There's no output as well, it's just the multiplication.